# Go template : Howto print array[]string to <script type="application/ld+json">

Tags: go, go-templates

I have 1 array string contains many image url, how to display it in to application/ld+json

Please help me for resolve this problem!

Thanks all!

This is variable type slice contain many imageUrl

```
images := []string{
            "abc.com/1.jpg",
            "abc.com/2.jpg",
            "abc.com/3.jpg",
            "...",
        }
```

This is script in html

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@type": "NewsArticle",
    "mainEntityOfPage": {
        "@type": "WebPage",
        "@id": "{{$currentUrl}}"
    },
    "headline": "{{$postTile}}",
    "image": [
        "*i want show imageUrl at here*",
        "*i want show imageUrl at here*",
        "*i want show imageUrl at here*",
    ]
}
```

[Đọc truyện miễn phí](https://truyenmienphi.net)

Comment: You can use `range` to loop over slices inside templates. e.g `{{range .ImageSlice}}{{.}}{{end}}`.

Comment: We can not use range in script tag html, please double check. Thanks for comment.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/_gkPbRsDZ6Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just range over the images, as stated on @mkopriva comment:

`{{range .ImageSlice}}{{.}}{{end}}`

try on [this playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ZPW2pzhJBzD)

reference [template docs](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template)